# Prueba en python con playwright y unittest, ¿porqué no corre el módulo completo?

Tags: python, unittest

Soy regularmente nueva en esto de programación y en el trabajo me pidieron probar el login de una página de la empresa con python usando el módulo unittest y la herramienta de generar código de playwright. Esto es lo que llevo hasta el momento, tuve que poner en otra función (test_1) la parte de las acciones puesto que unittest no reconocía el comando "playwright.chromium.launch" y mandaba error pero ahora solo abre el navegador sin pasar a la otra función, no sé si alguien podría orientarme sobre el error o qué es lo que me falta para que funcione de manera correcta.

```
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright
from locators import Locators_evou
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
        browser = playwright.chromium.launch(channel ="chrome", headless=False,slow_mo=500)
        context = browser.new_context()

        page = context.new_page()
        page.goto("http://localhost:3000/")

    def test_1(page):   
        page.click(Locators_evou.user_Log)
        page.fill(Locators_evou.user_Log, "Liliana")
        page.click(Locators_evou.password_log)
        page.fill(Locators_evou.password_log, "1234")
        page.check(Locators_evou.session_Log)
        page.click(Locators_evou.login_log)

        assert page.is_visible("¡Bienvenido!")
        
    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        run(playwright)

   
if __name__=="__main__":
    #unittest.main()
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: no estas llamando a la función `test_1`